# What is the name of this method/effect where a character repeats the exact same sentence of another character?

Tags: film-techniques, terminology

Is there a name for this effect where a character says a sentence at the beginning of a movie and another one repeats the same sentence later.

Here is an example in Batman the Dark Knight with the sentence *"you either die a hero or you live long enough to see yourself become the villain"* :
- [A first time by Harvey Dent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_aQupiaCSA)
- [At the end of the movie by Batman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9c8w8ONAWM)

Answer (score 4):

[Repetition.](http://literarydevices.net/repetition/)

> Repetition is a literary device that repeats the same words or phrases a few times to make an idea clearer. There are several types of repetitions commonly used in both prose and poetry.
>
> As a rhetorical device, it could be a word, a phrase or a full sentence or a poetical line repeated to emphasize its significance in the entire text. Repetition is not distinguished solely as a figure of speech but more as a rhetorical device.

Specifically Epimone:

> Repetition of a phrase (usually a question) to stress a point.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the common term is simply "repetition".

http://literarydevices.net/repetition/

---

It's interesting that the term **analepsis** is broadly defined as a repeated flashback of a scene for emphasis or effect, because flashbacks are a modern device most often utilized in cinema.

However, [this site](http://phrontistery.info/rhetoric.html) which is focused on rhetorical devices, defines analepsis as "repetition of a word or phrase for emphasis", which is surely an older meaning. *(The craft of rhetoric goes back to at least Ancient Greece, long before the modern forms of narrative which use flashbacks.)*